# isc-dhcp-server: Job failed to sart

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I am configuring the isc-dhcp-server on Ubuntu 12.04

My eth0 adapter has a static ip

The `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

The `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.100.100;
option domain-name "cauir.upv.es";
default-lease-time 3600;
max-lease-time 4000;
authoritative;
subnet 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
    option broadcast-address 192.168.100.255;
    option routers 192.168.100.100;
    host ubuntu{
        hardware eth0:02:03:04:05:ff;
        fixed-address 192.168.100.120;
    }
    host windows7{
        hardware eth0:02:03:04:ff:02;
        fixed-address 192.168.100.130;
    }
}
```

I am using `service isc-dhcp-server start` and I got: `start: Job failed to start`

If I use `initctl restart isc-dhcp-server` I got `initctl: Unknown instance:`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is logged during the failed attempt to start in */var/log/syslog`? You also should consider to update to a newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 15: expecting a network hardware type
#011#011hardware eth0:

Comment: Solved changing eth0 to ethernet and adding a space...

Comment: @Juanker I recommend [posting an answer about that](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use **ethernet** before mac address

```
    host ubuntu{
        hardware ethernet 0:02:03:04:05:ff;
        fixed-address 192.168.100.120;
    }
    host windows7{
        hardware ethernet 0:02:03:04:ff:02;
        fixed-address 192.168.100.130;
    }
```